# Slurm srun from aprun

Tags: slurm

I am used to running with aprun, and my run command looks like

```
aprun -n 432 -d 1 -j1 ./exec |& tee out.log
```

I would like to do this on a system using slurm, but I don't know the syntax for the command.  How does this translate over using srun?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That would be

```
srun --ntasks 432 --cpus-per-tasks 1 --threads-per-core 1 ./exec |& tee out.log
```